# CodeIgniter flashdata delay

Tags: codeigniter

I'm tring to validate a login form and sending error messages using flashdata. Flashdata seems to have a delay, it's only affected a second submit (no error message is shown after first submit, ok after second), whereas userdata works correctly.

View>

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error_messages')): ?>
  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error_messages'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo form_open('user/login', array('name' => 'login_form', 'id' => 'login_form')); ?>
<fieldset>
  <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Username: ', 'username'); ?>
    <?php echo form_input('username', set_value('username', ''), array('id' => 'username', 'placeholder' => 'username')); ?>
  </p>
  <p>
    <?php echo form_label('Password: ', 'password'); ?>
    <?php echo form_password('password', set_value('password', ''), array('id' => 'password', 'placeholder' => '********')); ?>
 </p>
 <p>
   <?php echo form_submit('login', 'Login', array('id' => 'login')); ?>
 </p>
```

Controller action>

```
public function login() {
    //user is not logged in, carry on
    if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
        //check if form was already submitted, if yes validate
        if ($this->input->post('login')) {
            $this->load->library('chronos_user');

            //gather data from form
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            //validate form, show error messages if not valid
            if (
                !($this->chronos_user->valid_username($username)) ||
                !($this->chronos_user->unique_username($username))
            )
            {
                $this->chronos_template->set_data('header', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'title' => 'Login'));
                $this->chronos_template->set_view('content', 'user/login_view');
                $this->chronos_template->view();
            }
            //redirect if ok
            else {
                header("Location http://c4studio.ro");
            }
        }
        //if no form was submitted, just display it
        else {
            $this->chronos_template->set_data('header', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'title' => 'Login'));
            $this->chronos_template->set_view('content', 'user/login_view');
            $this->chronos_template->view();            
        }
    }
    //user is already logged in, redirect to profile page
    else {
        $profile_url = "Location: ";
        $profile_url .= site_url();
        $profile_url .= "user/profile/";

        header($profile_url);
    }
}
```

Valid_username method>

```
    public function valid_username($username) {
        if (empty($username)) {

            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('error_messages', 'Value.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        if (strlen($username) < 3) {
            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('error_messages', 'Value11.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Any ideas? Also if somebody knows a better way to do all this please let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) flashdata exists at the *next server request*.

But in your case you actually set the flashdata in the same server request as you show the login view which was unsuccesful. Thats the reason it doesn't work.

A better way wuld to just allow your model method to return true or false and use that value instead. The flashdata should only be considered if you redirect the user to an error page or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

As @Repox mentioned, it only works on the 'next refresh'.  You are assuming that flashdata works RIGHT AWAY when you set it, but it doesn't you need an new actual page reload / refresh before that is available.

You have the right idea, but you are just using flashdata to implement your message, stick to form messages as a return result, or just a custom variable.

This is really a case of developers designing flashdata for one thing, and users using it for another.

You need to use `form_error` to return all form errors, don't use flashdata, it will not work as you expect it to.

**Examples:**
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors

> You can also override any error message found in the language file.
>   For example, to change the message for the "required" rule you will do
>   this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Your custom message here');
```